# Android : Not able to publish the Jacoco code coverage report on azure devops pipeline

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, azure-devops, code-coverage, jacoco

I'm setting up android project on azure pipeline. Where I'm running the unit tests and after successful execution of test cases want to generate the code coverage report.

I have created task in azure-pipelines yml file for running the JacocoTestReport through the script and also mentioned the required path for generating the report.

```
// This for running the jacocoTestReport
- script:
   ./gradlew jacocoTestReport

// This for publishing the code coverage result

- task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@1
     inputs:
     codeCoverageTool: 'Jacoco'
     summaryFileLocation: 
'/Users/vsts/agent/2.153.2/work/1/s/app/build/reports/jacoco/jacocoTestReport/html/index.html'
```

I expect the report should be generated in html file and got published on code coverage tab of azure-pipeline but In my case I am able to generate he report in artifact folder but not able to see it on code coverage tab and I am getting below error after above task :

```
Reading code coverage summary from '/Users/vsts/agent/2.153.2/work/1/s/app/build/reports/jacoco/jacocoTestReport/html/index.html'
##[warning]No coverage data found. Check the build errors/warnings for more details.
```

Answer (score 0):

[Gradle JaCoCo Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html) able to produce report not only in HTML format, but also in XML.

Argument `summaryFileLocation` of [Azure Pipelines `PublishCodeCoverageResults` task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/publish-code-coverage-results?view=azure-devops) must point to this XML file instead of HTML.

Comment: Thanks @godin but now I am getting below error on code coverage tab.
`Code coverage report cannot be rendered as report HTML was not found. Please verify that "Report Directory" containing an HTML report was specified when publishing code coverage.
`

Comment: Have you tried to follow and read the posted link? There is also parameter `reportDirectory` to specify path to HTML report.